# VSTS webpack build task cannot find CLI

Tags: asp.net, webpack, azure-devops

I have a .NET (4.7) Web Application inside a project directory called MyWebApp.Web

As part of the build process I run `npm install`, webpack-cli is a dependency.

But when I run the [webpack build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dealogic.webpack-vsts-extension#overview) with MyWebApp.Web set as the working directory I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\a\1\s\MyWebApp.Web\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)
```

If I try and run webpack via an NPM script I get webpack's built in interactive "a CLI must be installed" prompt, indicating that the module cannot be found.

Is there anything I'm missing that needs to be in place for webpack to "see" the node modules?

Comment: Are you sure your npm packages are being installed correctly? Are you using npm install with the production flag turned on? That would prevent your dev dependencies from being installed.

Comment: @Calidus well this is embarrassing, NODE_ENV was inndeed set to 'production'. Turned the flag off now webpack is running fine.

Comment: @JasonElkin The issue was resolved right? Then you could post your solution as an answer and accept it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It transpires that in the Variables tab `process.env.NODE_ENV` was set to `production` so dev dependencies were not being installed.

Removing this environment variable solved the problem.

I was doing this specifically to invoke webpack's "production" mode (partly because that's how the [webpack Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner) works). This approach always worked on dev environments because the modules were already installed from previous development builds but on the VSTS build agent we were only ever running a production build.

I've now set up separate webpack.common.js, webpack.config.js (for dev), and webpack.prod.js files using `webpack-merge`, as per the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/). This targets different configs to different environments rather than relying on environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
npm i webpack webpack-cli -g --save-dev
```

Comment: That just re-installs the packages that were already installed when `npm install` ran initially. The webpack build task still fails as if the ./MyWebApp.Web/node_modules/ dir is not there.

Comment: It actually installing it globally; have you tried removing the node_modules folder and doing `npm i` ?

Comment: Not exactly, this is a VSTS build task. VSTS pulls from the repository every build (so node modules is empty) and runs through a serious of build tasks, `npm i` being one of them. I know how to debug webpack and make it work locally etc. my problem here is VSTS specific.